# How do I setup a wireless connection for a LAN to WAN build up between two Routers

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, lan

Im an enthusiast in Networking & I like to play around a lot with wireless networks, LAN, Routers, Switches etc.  Well he other day I came accross a setup wherein two routers could be wired together either on a LAN to LAN basis or LAN to WAN basis where the latter would separate networks between the primary & secondary routers. Now as per the LAN to WAN setup the secondary router would have its WAN port connected with a ethernet cable originating from any one LAN port of the primary router. 
Getting this right a question flashed in my mind as to, can this setup i.e. LAN to WAN be made wireless rather than a wired connection? I don' t know if this sounds crazy or impossible but this is my Query!!!

Well any solution to the query would be greatly appreciated..

Thanks in advance...

Ross

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it can. The easiest way is to configure an access point in client mode to connect to the existing WiFi network and connect it to the router's WAN port. The router can be left at default settings except for things you specifically want to change.

Comment: But dude the WAN signal should turn on green on the wireless router. Secondly the DHCP link down would show 0.0.0.0 Any suggestions

Comment: @user182437 I don't understand what you're asking.

Comment: OK then why would the DHCP of the WAN configuration show 0.0.0.0 on the secondary router?

Comment: @user182437 It sounds like the access point is not configured correctly. If you connect it to a computer, do you get Internet access?

Comment: So I have to connect the ethernet cable to the secondary routers WAN port. Am i Right?

Comment: yes that would be in repeater mode. DHCP is auto turned off on the secondary router

Comment: The AP should be in client mode, not repeater. And DHCP should be *on* in the secondary router. You said you want a LAN to WAN build up, right? So the LAN will need a DHCP server. (You asked how to do LAN to WAN, I told you how to do LAN to WAN, but you seem to be doing half LAN to WAN, half LAN to LAN.)

Comment: OK sorry dude. When You asked me whether I could connect to the internet. yes I could do but only in repeater mode.                          So now once I turn off the repeater mode I should select Client out of the four options 1.AP 2.AP+WDS 3.Client 4.WDS in my wireless settings.

Comment: @user182437 Right. The second router is a client of the first router. The first router's LAN is the second router's WAN. The client connection puts the AP in the first router's LAN, which is where the second router's WAN needs to be.